# Angular 2 event not working

Tags: angular

I have been trying to find a solution to my problem but so far haven't found anything to fix it yet.

The problem is that my custom event is not picked up by the parent component.
The console.log "Event emitted" shows up in the console but the actual event is not picked up by the AppComponent.

What have I done wrong here?

**app.component.ts**

```
import { InventoryService } from './providers/inventory.service';
import { Component, OnInit, NgModule } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'apk-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
  providers: [InventoryService]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  articles;

  constructor(private inventoryService: InventoryService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {}

   onGetItems(amount: number) {
     console.log(amount);
     this.inventoryService.getArticles(amount).subscribe(data => this.articles = data);
   }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<apk-navbar (getArticlesEvent)="onGetItems($event)"></apk-navbar>

  <table class="highlight centered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Namne</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
    <tr *ngFor="let article of articles">
      <td>{{article.name}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

---

**navbar.component.ts**

```
import { Component, NgModule, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
      selector: 'apk-navbar',
      templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.scss']
    })
    export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {

      @Output() getArticlesEvent: EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter();

      constructor() { }

      ngOnInit() {  }

      onGetArticles(amount: number){
        console.log("Event emitted");
        this.getArticlesEvent.emit(amount);
      }

    }
```

**navbar.component.html**

```
    <div class="nav-content">
        <ul class="tabs tabs-transparent">
          <li class="tab"><span><a (click)="onGetArticles(20)">Articles</a></span></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Tried your code, and it worked fine for me. Please reproduce the issue in a plunker/stackblitz :)

Comment: @AJT_82 https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ealapc does not seem to work there either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When provided stackblitz, you have added your nav component as being bootstrapped, you only bootstrap the app component, so remove it from your NgModule, and only bootstrap...

```
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
```

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zadnqd?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)**

---

*as an unrelated issue, I just want to point out, that you need to inject the services in your constructor, not declare them as variables in your components. Check the demo, I updated that as well.*

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you did mistake in EventEmitter declaration. Try in this way:

```
@Output() getArticlesEvent = new EventEmitter<number>();
```

---

If that does not help, I guess that problem would be in place, where you called *onGetArticles* method.

Try call this method by click on span, in this way:

```
<li class="tab"><span (click)="onGetArticles(20)"><a>Articles</a></span></li>
```

---

or by prevent default action, in this way:

```
<li class="tab"><span><a (click)="onGetArticles($event, 20)">Articles</a></span></li>
```

and change your method in this way:

```
onGetArticles(event, amount: number) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.getArticlesEvent.emit(amount);
}
```

Comment: That did not seem to work either. I tried putting the EventEmitter in ngOnInit() and makes it so AppComponent picks up the Event. But since I want the event to trigger when I press a button, I cannot use this approach

Comment: @speccaN I updated my answer to help you... telle me, if it was helped

Comment: That did not work either :/ thanks for the help though!